# Can you debug a .cshtml file using Jetbrains Rider?

Tags: razor, rider

Am I missing something or is it not possible to put a breakpoint on a .cshtml view using Rider?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Now it's not possible for now. We're working on implementation and you can track state in the issue [RIDER-1642](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-1642)

UPDATE: should work in EAP 17